# Read websites text on Chrome/Firefox/Edge mobile

Tags: browser, text-to-speech, reading

Is there any way (e.g. extension) for text reading (text-to-speech) from websites through mobile browsers Chrome/Firefox/Edge, etc.? I'm at the Android latest.

Comment: You may want to replace "I'm at the Android latest" with an Android version number.  It's unlikely "Android latest" will remain constant over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For Chrome & Chrome Canary nothing worked despite many internet claims of turning on the 'Read Aloud' flag from chrome://flags to enable.
- I didn't try on Edge
- On Firefox `117.1.0`, the add-on *Read aloud-Text to Speech* can be enabled, and it works. You need to open a site and tap on add-ons, select this to read aloud (note: certain pages like Mozilla help pages are not read aloud)

[image]

You can select various read-aloud options as below:

[image]

Comment: BTW, the reason that Mozilla pages are not read aloud is because of a security policy that prevents extensions from operating on Mozilla's pages.  Otherwise, a single bad extension could potentially install more bad extensions.